# Merge two columns of array struct with different fields

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have a dataframe of schema

```
        StructType(
        [
            StructField('product_id', IntegerType(), True),
            StructField('tenant_id', IntegerType(), True),
            StructField("materials", ArrayType(StructType([
              StructField('id', IntegerType(), True),
              StructField('percentage', FloatType(), True)]
            ))),
            StructField("elastic", ArrayType(StructType([
              StructField('id', IntegerType(), True),
              StructField('name', MapType(StringType(), StringType()), True)
          ])))
        ])
```

And I want to merge the two structs in order to have a new one with the 3 fields, id, percentage and name where the materials.id = elastic.id like:

```
        StructType(
        [
            StructField('product_id', IntegerType(), True),
            StructField('tenant_id', IntegerType(), True),
            StructField("materials", ArrayType(StructType([
              StructField('id', IntegerType(), True),
              StructField('percentage', FloatType(), True),
              StructField('name', MapType(StringType(), StringType()), True)]
            )))
        ])
```

Basically,

I want to pass from this
[Before and expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KubLn.png)

I tried with udf and results but in terms of performance is not the best approach.

```
        @udf(returnType=ArrayType(StructType([
            StructField("id", IntegerType(), False),
            StructField('percentage', FloatType(), True),
            StructField('name', MapType(StringType(), StringType()), True)
        ])))
        def expand_list(materials, elastic):
            final = []
            for k in materials:
              for i in elastic:
                if k.id == i.id:
                  final += [{'id': k.id, 'percentage': k.percentage, 'name': i.name}]
            return final
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/api/sql/index.html#transform) to iterate over the first array and then use [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/api/sql/index.html#filter) to find the corresponding entry in the second array:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# some testdata
testdata="""
  {"product_id": 1, "tenant_id": 1, "materials": [{"id": 1, "percentage": 0.1}, {"id": 3, "percentage": 0.3}, {"id": 2, "percentage": 0.2}], "elastic": [{"id": 1, "name": "one"},{"id":2, "name": "two"}] }
"""
df = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([testdata]))

# create a new column with the merged array
df.withColumn("merged_materials", F.expr("""
  transform(materials, m -> named_struct(
      'id', m.id, 
      'percentage', m.percentage, 
      'name', filter(elastic, e -> e.id == m.id)[0].name)
    )
    """
  )).show(vertical=True, truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
-RECORD 0----------------------------------------------------------
 elastic          | [{1, one}, {2, two}]                           
 materials        | [{1, 0.1}, {3, 0.3}, {2, 0.2}]                 
 product_id       | 1                                              
 tenant_id        | 1                                              
 merged_materials | [{1, 0.1, one}, {3, 0.3, null}, {2, 0.2, two}]
```